# LINQ to SQL many to many relationship with properties - C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, orm, many-to-many

I've just started a project using LINQ to SQL, and I've clashed against the many-to-many
problem. I've found a lot of possible solution, and I've choose [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39104/LINQ-to-SQL-Many-to-Many-Relationships).

Anyway, the affected db tables look like this:

```
Customer (idcustomer,other stuff..)
Customer_Role(idcustomer, idrole, other_attribute_I_want_to_keep )
Role(idrole, other stuff)
```

Now on, how can I handle the "other_attribute_I_want_to_keep?
It would be great to have it like this:

Customer c.Role.other_attribute_I_want_to_keep, but I cannot spot a possible solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use many-to-many for this.  Rather you'll need to make CustomerRole a first class object that `BelongsTo` both a Customer and a Role.  Customer and Role in turn should be each declare a `HasOne` attribute for CustomerRole.  Then you can do:

```
c.CustomerRole.Role
c.CustomerRole.OtherAttribute
```

You can make a shortcut `Role` attribute on `Customer` defined as:

```
[NotMapped]
public Role Role { 
    get { return CustomerRole == null ? (Role)null : CustomerRole.Role; } 
    set { if (CustomerRole == null)
            CustomerRole = new CustomerRole(){ Role = value };
          else
            CustomerRole.Role = value;
    }
}
```

but be aware that you may run into trouble using this shortcut when building a complex query.

Comment: That would be a solution if no other is possible, otherwise, is it possible to make "CustomerRole" a Dictionary<idrole,customerRole> instead of a IEnumerable<CustomerRole>?

Comment: I'm not sure how you intend to such a Dictionary, can you elaborate?

Comment: sorry, but how can a CustomerRole attribute could possibly be ok? I mean, it's a collection, so it would be CustomerRoleS, and I cannot understand how the shortcut attribute you have defined coud work

Comment: sorry, of course: suppose I have a "Customer" entity, with LINQ to SQL I have direct access to the "CustomerRoles" collection. It would be nice if it can be a Dictionary (with idrole as key) instead of a IEnumerable flat collection

Comment: you can easily make a dictionary using `context.CustomerRoles.ToDictionary(cr => cr.IdRole)`

Comment: wouldn't it be somehow inefficient?

Comment: It's not inefficient if you want a dictionary that contains all CustomerRoles.  I strongly suspect that a Dictionary is not exactly what you need, but without more information on what you are trying to accomplish (code example) I can't really assist.  Perhaps try asking this as another question with details in code/pseudocode on what exactly you want to accomplish.

Comment: Also, regarding your comment "I mean, it's a collection, so it would be CustomerRoleS", you can define CustomerRole as `HasOne`, not `HasMany` so it won't be a collection.  If you need the ability to associate multiple Roles per a single Customer (this wasn't clear in your question), you can lookup the first CustomerRole that matches a specific IdRole (e.g. `CustomerRoles.First(cr => cr.IdRole == role.IdRole)`), and you can make that a helper method to avoid reusing that code.

Comment: Of course, but it would not make many sense to have a One-to-Many mapped as a One-One relationship :)